# OpenDaylight Flow statistics using RPC call

Tags: rpc, openflow, opendaylight

I'm trying to get statistics using the following RPC call and not via the default statistics-manager.

```js
POST / restconf / operations / opendaylight - flow - statistics: get - all - flows - statistics - from - all - flow - tables {
    "input": {
        "node": "/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id=\"openflow:1000\"]"
    }
}
```

However, the response of this request is just `transaction-id`. While I can see the OpenFlow `Flow Stat Request` and `Flow Stat Reply` messages are exchanged between the controller and the switch, the operational datastore seems not to be updated as a result of calling the above RPC. I check the operational datastore using:

```
GET /restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node/openflow:1000/table/0
```

My question is:

- How can I get the flow statistics sent to the controller by the switch as a result of the above RPC (`get-all-flows-statistics-from-all-flow-tables`)? And why is the operational datastore is not updated?

Thanks! Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Boron, what you're trying to use is deprecated, hence you should use the following:

1. Install `odl-openflowplugin-flow-services`
2. Connect your switch
3. Send the following request:

```js
    POST /restconf/operations/opendaylight-direct-statistics:get-node-connector-statistics
    Host: localhost:8181
    Content-Type: application/json
    Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=

    {
        "input": 
        { 
            "node" : "/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id=\"openflow:187811733353539\"]" ,
            "store-stats" : false
        } 
    }
```

4. Set store-stats to `true` if you want to keep them in the datastore.

You can also get the stats only for a specified port, but while trying, it appears not to be working well
Add this to the above payload:

```js
    "node-connector-id" : "/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id=\"openflow:187811733353539\"]/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:187811733353539:LOCAL']",
```

Instead of `LOCAL`, specify the port you want.

Hope this helps,
Alexis